# How SQLAlchemy sends large data

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I use ORM to update 100000 rows of a table's column. I do it in one DB session. It is sort of like

```
for model in models: # 100000 model objects are queried
    model.a = 1
db_session.commit()
```

My question is how SQLAlchemy sends the update information to the postgres database? It sends within one connection, or it opens many connections underhood and sends the data concurrently? I am asking because when I ran the script, the database's connections were maxed. I am investigating whether the maxed connections was due to my script.

Comment: 1 connection per session/transaction.